# What are the differences between the races in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

(Alternate title: How can I float like a turian and sting like a drell)?

I know that each race has different abilities available to it (eg. a human adept has different abilities than an asari adept), **what other differences exist between races**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aside from the [obvious class limitations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55659/in-mass-effect-3-what-are-the-race-class-combinations-hidden-bonus-ones), where the races differentiate the most is **Evasion and Mobility**, **Melee and Heavy Melee Abilities**, **Base Health/Shielding**, and their **Racial Passive**. All Racial Passives have increased Power/Weapon Damage and Weight Capacity bonuses for various weapon types, however, the ratios of these bonuses vary per passive.

### Asari

- **Base Health/Barrier:** 500/500
- **Evasion and Mobility:** Asari slide on biotic energy, which uses 10% of their barrier for each use.
- **Melee and Heavy Melee Abilities:** For their Heavy Melee, they unleash a PBAoE (Point Blank Area of Effect) biotic pulse (similar to [Nova](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Nova), except the charge up time is longer, as is standard with Heavy Melee attacks).
- **Unique Passive:** [Asari Justicar](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Asari_Justicar#Mass_Effect_3)

### Drell

- **Base Health/Barrier:** 500/250
- **Evasion and Mobility:** Drell do flips for evasion, during which [they take 50% less damage](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/9308589/2#9311088). They also have 15% faster movement speed.
- **Melee and Heavy Melee Abilities:** They use martial arts for their regular melee attacks, but have the [standard class-based Heavy Melee](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_%28Mass_Effect_3%29#Heavy_Melee).
- **Unique Passive:** [Drell Assassin](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Drell_Assassin#Mass_Effect_3)

### Humans

- **Base Health/Barrier (or Shielding):** 500/500
- **Evasion and Mobility:** Humans can do a combat roll in any direction, both in and out of cover.
- **Melee and Heavy Melee Abilities:** Standard
- **Unique Passive:** [Alliance Training](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Alliance_Training). Humans are the only race that can get a weight decrease to *all* weapons.

### Krogan

- **Base Health/Shielding:** 750/1,000
- **Evasion and Mobility:** Krogan do *not* have an evasion mechanism and also move slower. Unlike Turians, they *cannot* roll from cover to cover.
- **Melee and Heavy Melee Abilities:** Their regular melee is a headbutt, and they have a unique heavy melee ability, Krogan Charge, which lets them charge and swing their weapon, causing knockback and staggering.
- **Unique Passives:** [Krogan Berserker](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Krogan_Berserker_%28power%29#Mass_Effect_3) and [Rage](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Rage_%28power%29) (replaces [Fitness](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Fitness_%28multiplayer%29))

### Quarians

- **Base Health/Shielding:** 500/600
- **Evasion and Mobility:** Quarians do a jump to the side as their strafing evade rather than a combat roll.
- **Melee and Heavy Melee Abilities:** Standard
- **Unique Passive:** [Quarian Defender](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Quarian_Defender)

### Salarians

- **Base Health/Shielding:** 500/600
- **Evasion and Mobility:** Salarians do a jump to the side as their strafing evade, same as Quarians.
- **Melee and Heavy Melee Abilities:** Standard
- **Unique Passive:** [Salarian Operative](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Salarian_Operative)

### Turians

- **Base Health/Shielding:** 500/750
- **Evasion and Mobility:** Turians, like Krogan, do not have any way to evade or strafe and move slower. However, they *can* roll from cover to cover.
- **Melee and Heavy Melee Abilities:** Standard
- **Unique Passive:** [Turian Veteran](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Turian_Veteran). They are the only class that can receive a bonus to Weapon Stability.

---

The **Resurgence Pack DLC** added the Geth and Batarian races. You need to download it in order for the new races to show up in the store packs for you.

### Batarians

- **Base Health/Shielding:** 750/750
- **Evasion and Mobility:** Batarians have the same movement limitations as Krogan. They do not have a way to evade or strafe, are unable to roll from cover to cover, and have a slightly slower overall movement speed.
- **Melee and Heavy Melee Abilities:** Standard regular melee. They have a unique heavy melee which takes a long time to charge, but it pretty much pulverizes your target, doing massive damage, causing knockback and quite a bit of blood spatter.
- **Unique Passive:** [Batarian Enforcer](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Batarian_Enforcer). Batarians are the only race that can get a Spare Ammo capacity bonus as a passive. In addition, they can get a weight decrease to both Sniper Rifles *and* Shotguns.

### Geth

- **Base Health/Shielding:** 250/750
- **Evasion and Mobility:** Geth do a strafing evade outside of cover similar to the Quarians and Salarians. Like the Krogan, they *cannot* roll from cover to cover. They get movement speed bonuses in their passive.
- **Melee and Heavy Melee Abilities:** Standard regular melee. The Geth Heavy Melee is a bit similar to the Asari's. It's a PBAoE pulse that uses your shields to power it (again, similar to Nova) for as long as you hold down the Heavy Melee button or until your shields run out, whichever comes first. Higher shields will let you do this longer, so in Hunter Mode, which costs you 50% of your shields, it won't last as long.
- **Unique Passives:** [Networked AI](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Networked_AI), [Advanced Hardware](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Advanced_Hardware) (replaces Fitness), and [Hunter Mode](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter_Mode). Geth can receive a weapon damage bonus to Geth weapons, and like the Batarians, can also receive a reduction in weapon weight for two types of weapons instead of one type, Assault and Sniper Rifles. Hunter Mode, when active, lets you see through smoke and architecture, in order to locate enemies, who show up with red glowing auras. There is a 50% penalty to your shields while this ability is active.

Comment: Also: Drell vanguard has a unique melee, from what I've seen.

Comment: @mike1987 I noticed that too, his move is more of a combat takedown rather than a standard punch

Comment: do krogans regenerate health by any chance?

Comment: @yx. I can't confirm that or the base health of them because I haven't managed to unlock one yet. :( Please feel free to edit in the info if you get one!

Comment: Does this have any additional info?: http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/9308589

Comment: @NickT Somewhat... Stuff like "Toughness" and "Weapon Expert" are rather vague. I'm going to restructure this answer to singular races, now that I have more unlocked and compare the racial passives, now that I have numbers for most of them.

Comment: Re Breathing Underwater: `Yes the breathing under water is a joke :P Everything else is as good as gold.` (From the thread Nick linked.)

Comment: @LessPop Thanks, I managed to totally miss that one when I skimmed the thread, haha.

Comment: The krogan base health is actually 750/1000, at least for a level 1 krogan soldier.  Also, they don't regenerate health bars, which is a bummer :P

Comment: @yx. Thanks for the info! Still waiting to unlock a Krogan. :(

Comment: Pst! Time to update this again! (Also, Krogan have RAGE instead of Fitness)

Answer (score 4):

Each race also has it's own variants of melee and heavy melee attacks.

Krogan are notable in this case, since their heavy melee attack is actually able to stagger Atlas mechs.

Answer (score 1):

Krogans also have vastly superior health and shields, though I don't remember their base stats (think its 700 health, 900 shield or something, please anyone correct me on this).

Answer (score 0):

Turian Soldiers also use the Sentinel Heavy Melee and I heard somewhere that all Turians get a stability/accuracy buff.