# In Mass Effect 3, What are the Race/Class Combinations & Hidden Bonus ones?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

**Multiplayer Related Question**

I am unable to access any Mass Effect 3 Wikia pages from my internet as it is restriction due to a work gateway, however I was discussing something with a few collegues of mine.

We were wondering what Class/Race combinations are available on ME3 multiplayer. And hidden ones?

or example: I know the soldier has Male Human, Female Human, Turian, Krogan and a bonus Soldier from battlefield 3.

Could someone give the the information here instead of directing me to a Wikia?

Comment: very similar to [What are the differences between the races in multiplayer?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53640/what-are-the-differences-between-the-races-in-multiplayer)

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes different questions and answers, this one is just asking for a list of what races are available for which class, which is totally unanswered in the other q

Comment: @BenBrocka - You are right, different questions, different answers. Though Similar, I did check beforehand. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copied exactly from [the Mass Effect 3 Wikia](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer#Powers), included with the powers per races:

> **Adept**
>
> - *Human*: Warp, Singularity, Shockwave, Alliance Training, Fitness
>     (Adept)
> - *Asari*: Stasis, Warp, Throw, Asari Justicar, Fitness (Adept)
> - *Drell*: Reave, Pull, Cluster Grenade, Drell Assassin, Fitness (Adept)
>
> **Soldier**
>
> - *Human*: Adrenaline Rush, Concussive Shot, Frag Grenade, Alliance
>     Training, Fitness** (Soldier)
> - *Krogan*: Carnage, Fortification, Inferno Grenade, Krogan Berserker,
>     Rage
> - *Turian*: Marksman, Concussive Shot, Proximity Mine, Turian Veteran,
>     Fitness (Soldier)
> - *Battlefield 3*:1 Adrenaline Rush, Carnage, Frag Grenade, Alliance
>     Training, Fitness (Soldier)
>
> **Engineer**
>
> - *Human*: Incinerate, Overload, Combat Drone, Alliance Training, Fitness
>     (Engineer)
> - *Quarian*: Incinerate, Cryo Blast, Sentry Turret, Quarian Defender,
>     Fitness (Engineer)
> - *Salarian*: Incinerate, Energy Drain, Decoy, Salarian Operative,
>     Fitness (Engineer)
>
> **Sentinel**
>
> - *Human*: Throw, Warp, Tech Armor, Alliance Training, Fitness (Sentinel)
> - *Turian*: Warp, Overload, Tech Armor, Turian Veteran, Fitness
>     (Sentinel)
> - *Krogan*: Incinerate, Lift Grenade, Tech Armor, Krogan Berserker, Rage
>
> **Infiltrator**
>
> - *Human*: Sticky Grenade, Tactical Cloak, Cryo Blast, Alliance Training,
>     Fitness (Infiltrator)
> - *Salarian*: Energy Drain, Tactical Cloak, Proximity Mine, Salarian
>     Operative, Fitness (Infiltrator)
> - *Quarian*: Sticky Grenade, Tactical Cloak, Sabotage, Quarian Defender,
>     Fitness (Infiltrator)
>
> **Vanguard**
>
> - *Human*: Biotic Charge, Shockwave, Nova, Alliance Training, Fitness
>     (Vanguard)
> - *Drell*: Biotic Charge, Pull, Cluster Grenade, Drell Assassin, Fitness
>     (Vanguard)
> - *Asari*: Biotic Charge, Stasis, Lift Grenade, Asari Justicar, Fitness
>     (Vanguard)

Answer (score 1):

You can be a Human male or female in any of the 6 classes, and the Human options are unlocked from the start. Alien races are listed below, and are only unlockable via the Veteren item pack or better in the store.

**Adept**:  Asari, Drell
**Engineer**: Quarian, Salarian
**Infiltrator**: Quarian, Salarian
**Sentinel**: Krogan, Turian
**Soldier**: Krogan, Turian. There's also a bonus Battlefield 3 class if you sign into Origin with an account that has a Battlefield 3 online pass activated.
**Vanguard**: Asari, Drell

A nice table is available [on the Mass Effect Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer#Class_and_Race) as well.

Comment: I can't access the ME3 wikia as stated in my original question.

Comment: @mike1987 I know, I left the link for people who have access. Did you want more than just the races and class combinations? They're all there