# What are all the skills and special abilities of each multiplayer class?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between the races in multiplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53640/what-are-the-differences-between-the-races-in-multiplayer)

Can someone post a link (or just post here) the powers and special abilities of each class?  (i.e. krogans can do a melee charge, drell does a flip kick, etc).

Comment: feel free to close if its on the site already, I couldn't easily find it via search

Comment: I think the powers for each race/class might have been covered (don't have a link tho) but I'm pretty sure we haven't covered the special abilities like heavy melees or dodges.

Comment: Race differences covered here: [What are the differences between the races in multiplayer?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53640/what-are-the-differences-between-the-races-in-multiplayer) Race abilities covered here: [In Mass Effect 3, What are the Race/Class Combinations & Hidden Bonus ones?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55659/in-mass-effect-3-what-are-the-race-class-combinations-hidden-bonus-ones)

Comment: I suppose it is covered then!

Comment: Those questions would have been hard to find without the multiplayer tag.  That problem has now been fixed.