# What's included in the Resurgence Pack

Tags: mass-effect-3, me3-resurgence-pack

What new character classes, weapons, and powers are availible in the resurgence pack DLC?

What level of rarity are they? How can I find them?

Answer (score 6):

All of the items debuting in the Resurgance Packs are Gold-level rarity with the exception of the new consumables (which, like the other consumables, have common rarity). They can be found in regular Spectre / Veterans packs, or in the limited-time Reserves Pack (which guarantees one of these, available from the upcoming Operation: Resurgance).

Questions about the differences between the races should be directed [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53706/336).

Asari Justicar Adept

- [Biotic Sphere](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Biotic_Sphere)
- [Reave](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Reave)
- [Pull](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Pull)

Batarian Soldier

- [Ballistic Blades](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Ballistic_Blades)
- [Blade Armor](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Blade_Armor)
- [Inferno Grenade](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Inferno_Grenade)

Geth Engineer

- [Geth Turret](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Geth_Turret_%28power%29)
- [Hunter-Mode](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter_Mode)
- [Overload](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Overload)

Batarian Sentinel

- [Blade Armor](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Blade_Armor)
- [Shockwave](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Shockwave)
- [Submission Net](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Submission_Net)

Geth Infiltrator

- [Tactical Cloak](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Tactical_Cloak)
- [Proximity Mine](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Proximity_Mine)
- [Hunter-Mode](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter_Mode)

Krogan Battlemaster Vanguard

- [Charge](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Charge)
- [Carnage](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Carnage_%28power%29)
- [Barrier](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Barrier)

Sniper Rifle - [Kishock Harpoon Gun](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Kishock_Harpoon_Gun)

SMG - [Geth Plasma SMG](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Geth_Plasma_SMG)

Assault Rifle - [Striker](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Striker_Assault_Rifle)

The pack also included two new maps: Firebase: Hydra and Firebase: Condor.

Comment: "They can be found in regular Spectre / Veterans packs, or in the limited-time Resurgence Pack (which guarantees one of these)." •When/where is the Resurgence Pack that guarantees one of the items?

Comment: [Link](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Resurgence_Pack) to the wiki article.

Comment: @NoNameNeeded Next week, hopefully! There was a database error that prevented them from being activated properly, so we got premium spectre packs in the meanwhile.